# Convert Dict to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

When i want to convert an array to dict it put de name of the const inside it.

Want to convert this:

```
const hallo = {'name': 'Peter', 'lastname': 'Richard'}
```

To:

```
const arrayhallo = [{'name': 'Peter', 'lastname': 'Richard'}]
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
const arrayhallo = [{hallo}]
```

But it return:

```
[hallo: {'name': 'Peter', 'lastname': 'Richard'}]
```

I only want the dict into the array, but with .push or this way i keep getting first de name of the dict first as index.

Comment: `[{ ...hallo }]` or `[ hallo ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
let array1 = []
const hello = {'name': 'Peter', 'lastname': 'Richard'}
array1.push(hello)
console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather simple:

assigning an array with the only item being the variable with the object should do the job

```
const hallo = {'name': 'Peter', 'lastname': 'Richard'};
const arrayhallo = [hallo];
console.log(arrayhallo); // will return [{'name': 'Peter', 'lastname': 'Richard'}]
```

You can then add other objects to the array with arrayhallo.push(object)